# firebase.firestore() shows bizarre data and not my actual documents from the database/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying firebase firestore by...

```
let database = firebase.firestore();
let places = database.collection("place");
console.log("places", places);
```

now the logged data is bizarre and not the actual documents..

here is a picture of the log...can you please advice regarding tackling this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all items in your collections called "place" you can do something like this:

```
let database = firebase.firestore();
let places = database.collection("place");

const querySnapshot = places.get()
// You can make an empty array to eventually push the items into
const collectionArray = []


    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data()
      collectionArray.push(data)
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    })
   console.log('collectionArray:',collectionArray)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code hasn't actually executed any query yet.  All it's done is build a Query object.

If you want to execute the query, call `get()` on it, and handle the results as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).

```
let database = firebase.firestore();
let query = database.collection("place");
query.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
        console.log("document", documentSnapshot.data());
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help Doug, really appreciate it. But I am accepting David's answer as he is new to the community, I am sure you will agree with me on this decision. :)